# Pass parameter to Apex controller on load

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a Visualforce page which needs to pass a parameter in order to redirect to the correct URL.

However when it runs it says the `logoutUrl` is null.

**VF**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="LogoutController" action="{!redirect}">
    <apex:param assignTo="{!logoutURL}" value="https://www.google.co.uk/logout" />
</apex:page>
```

**Apex**

```
public with sharing class LogoutController {

    public String logoutURL {get; set;}

    public LogoutController() {
        system.debug('Logout URL ' + logoutURL);
    }

    public PageReference redirect(){

        PageReference p = new PageReference(logoutURL);
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;

    }
}
```

Comment: In addition the the answer the param also needs the name property specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design won't work, because apex:param only works with apex:actionFunction, apex:actionPoller, apex:actionSupport, apex:commandButton, and apex:commandLink. As such, if you want to provide a parameter that way, you have to let the page load first:

```
<apex:page controller="LogoutController">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction name="logout" action="{!redirect}">
      <apex:param name="logoutURL" assignTo="{!logoutURL}" value="https://www.google.co.uk/logout" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <script>
      logout();
    </script>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Since this script is inline, it will run before the page shows anything more than a white background, but it is slightly slower than passing a value via URL parameter and redirecting on page load (as your original intent).

---

If you want to redirect without a controller, you can do this by placing a URL or formula that evaluates to a URL in the action attribute:

```
<!-- redirects directly -->
<apex:page action="https://www.google.co.uk/logout" />

<!-- redirects with a value from a label -->
<apex:page action="{!$Label.googleLogoutUrl}" />
```

Comment: Would there be anyway to redirect this without having the page load to execute the JS first?

Comment: @DeploymentFailure There's ways to load the URL ahead of time (e.g. using a custom label or URL parameter), but your specific method won't work without letting the page load. I'm actually curious why you're bothering to do this if the URL is just hard-coded anyways, since there's easier ways to redirect.

Comment: @DeploymentFailure For example: `<apex:page action="https://www.google.co.uk/logout" />` or even `<apex:page action="{!$Label.googleLogoutUrl}" />`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that was actually a feature, could you make that an answer? thanks

Comment: @DeploymentFailure Sure thing.